# I receive a type-mismatch error from VBA on one computer, but not on others. Why?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with macro. In this file, there is a user form. In the form, there is a Textbox. I call the user form "MyForm" and the TextBox "MyTextBox".

I also have a module. In this module there is a subroutine like this

```
Sub MySub(s As String)
    MyForm.MyTextBox.Value = s
    ...
End Sub
```

On most computers, the code above has no problem, while on one computer, it raises the type mismatch error. Can you explain this?

Please help me. I'm very frustated.

Many thanks in advance,

Haris

Comment: Does each computer have the same version of Excel?

Comment: s may be defined elsewhere. You can check this by using, say, myS instead. I have found using single letters for variables can bite from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things you could check (most of them obvious, I know).

-Versions of the spreadsheet between the various PCs.
-Culture on the problem PC
-Data on the problem PC
-The form being used with other forms/macros who also have a variable defined as "s"

What kind of data is usually entered into the textbox?