# Type mismatch on one PC but not other - run time error 13

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly simple macro that populates a variant array with both text and numbers. It works fine on my PC but not on my brothers, who's PC is new (using the same file/macro).  I have checked the excel versions and they are the same (2016 MSO 16.0.7571.7095) 32 bit, also the culture is the same - 1033 for both.  The error is run time 13 - Type mismatch. The windows are different though, 8.1 vs 10 - could it be that?

This is the only proper post I could find on the topic: [I receive a type-mismatch error from VBA on one computer, but not on others. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252259/i-receive-a-type-mismatch-error-from-vba-on-one-computer-but-not-on-others-why)

This is the code line on which the error is created:

```
    prArray(i, 1) = CDbl(Mid(prArray(i, O), 11, 7))
```

I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is the value of 'Mid(prArray(i, O), 11, 7)' when it errors out?

Comment: Wait, at copying pasting your piece of code I got an "O" (letter) instead of a "0" (zero). Check your code

Comment: A random guess. One of you use `Option Explicit` and one of you don't. The Windows version is almost certainly not the issue.

Comment: To add to my previous comment -- I am guessing that you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. That `O` vs `0` is almost a dead give away. If so, add it and see what happens.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the swift replies. You are correct on the Option Explicit, I added and fixed what needed to be fixed - noob mistake.  Though the error remains as originally.  The value is 3200.00 when it errors out, user3598756

Comment: No one has any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some frustration it is an easy fix after all, and comes down to `Culture` on the problem PC as answered here: [I receive a type-mismatch error from VBA on one computer, but not on others. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252259/i-receive-a-type-mismatch-error-from-vba-on-one-computer-but-not-on-others-why) . For interest, I checked the excel culture/language with this code:

```
Sub Detect_Language()
  MsgBox Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
End Sub
```

All that was necessary was to change the language settings of the PC itself at `Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Language`, to `US English` (it was different at the problem PC).